# site contact form not working

Tags: emails

My hosted site's contact form is not working. I have checked all the obvious things like:

- correct site email address.
- permissions
- spam box

It is working on the local development machine. I contacted the hosting company various times with no luck.

I have also dropped a PHP mail script into the root and calling it directly works. So PHP's mail function works, just not my contact form.

So my question now is, what alternatives can I explore, bar getting the co-operation of the hosting company, to fix this.

Comment: what are logs saying?

Comment: "not working" is perhaps the single least helpful problem description there is. It gives us practically _nothing_ to work with.

Comment: The question was not so much about getting to the root cause of the contact form not working, but about alternatives which @terrycb neatly answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is about what alternatives you could use, have you tried the PHPMailer library?  Here it is: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Another alternative could be the [Mandrill API](https://www.mandrill.com/). You could add a custom submission handler to your contact form, and in that, make your API call to Mandrill.

Just for sake of completeness, here's how I would approach it (using the [Mandrill PHP wrapper](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-php)):

```
//mymodule.module

require DRUPAL_ROOT . "/Mandrill.php";

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {



  if($form_id == "my_contact_form"){
    $form['#submit'][] = "mymodule_api_submit";
  }
}

function mymodule_api_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
  $mandrill = new Mandrill("PUT_AN_API_KEY_HERE");
  $message = array(
  'subject' => 'Test message',
  'from_email' => 'you@yourdomain.com',
  'text' => 'Message!',
  'to' => array(array('email' => 'email@domain', 'name' => 'TheirName')),);


  $mandrill->messages->send( $message );
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant. I installed PHPMailer and used Google Mail. Works like a charm!